# Smooth MacOS under heavy load possible?

Tags: macos, hardware-recommendation

I do various development work on a 13" 2015 RMBP with 8 GB of RAM and a dual core i5, always using the latest MacOS. The experience is painful, to say the least. Every IDE's UI is laggy, and Xcode is the worst. Finder is laggy. Chrome is laggy. Even when memory pressure is green and CPU is well under 100%, everything is still slow as molasses.

Of course, at any given time, I really need to have open at least two IDEs, multiple web browsers, multiple VMs, terminals, Finder sessions, iMessage, Slack, etc. But that would bring the system to a crawl, so I have to incur the cost of opening/closing these as needed.

Is it possible to get a smooth Mac experience under my ideal workload of having everything open at once? Is there any model of Mac that can handle that? Or is MacOS just fundamentally slow?

Comment: MacOS is fast enough, you're just running it on a machine that isn't & has barely enough RAM.. There's not much you can do except limit your expectations.

Comment: Agreed - I believe all of the 13ʺ models are 2-core. That's really not ideal for what you're looking to do.

Comment: If you're constantly running multiple IDEs and multiple VMs, you're better off looking for a heavy duty workstation.

Comment: @NoahL, since the Mac Pro is a little old, what other kind of workstation would you have in mind?

Comment: It depends on your budget/lifetime expectancy. Honestly, I was thinking a Mac Pro. Let's assume a budget of $2000 USD, a lifetime expectancy of ~5 years, and you don't mind losing official MacOS support in 1-2 years. A top of the line classic Mac Pro (2009-2012) (firmware 5,1; 2x 3.46 GHz hex-cores; 64GB RAM; 1-2TB storage, base GPU + new Nvidia graphics (say, GTX 970) should be cheaper than a new Mac Pro or iMac with similar geekbench results (and within the above budget). Mine gets a geekbench score of ~17,000.

Comment: I'm with @NoahL - I have a 4,1 with uprated firmware to 5,1 so it would run Sierra if I wanted [but I don't], dual 6-core 3.46Ghz Westmeres, 64GB RAM 1TB SSD [& 12TB HD] AMD HD 7950 ... cost under £2,000 It's quite the beast & doesn't really show its age. Geek bench 32,000 By comparison [for life expectancy] my 08 3,1 has been running 24/7 without sleeping, since 2008 & is still good, but of course slower.

Comment: @Tetsujin and I have almost exactly the same thing. how'd you get a 32k geekbench score??? (Are you not using geekbench 4?)

Comment: Geek bench 3. It was measured by the seller & I retested at the same numbers. I'll check again on GB4...

Comment: @NoahL -  OK… retested on GB4 ~19k & then again on GB3 ~30k. They've moved the goalposts between the two versions ;)  [I didn't shut everything down to measure, but there was nothing heavy running whilst I did them]